When updating Wsl I Get an Error
I have Windows 11 machines
I installed docker and after installing I got an error "wsl --update"
And when I run the code wsl --update in Windows PowerShell as Administrator
I got an error:
Checking for updates...
The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.

Of course, I have WSL installed.
I have uploaded the error image above my question


In an elevated Windows Terminal prompt run the following command:
sc config LxssManager start=auto

If the issue still happens repair the WSL install:



If you still have problems run the current MSI for WSL yourself. You can find that here
Source: Here

@mobin - The command I suggested absolutely should work, so you are either running an older version of WSL or perhaps don’t even have it installed. Which is the reason I suggested you run the MSI.
